# How do I access only specific variables in a PuLP problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

In an LP model that I solve with PuLP in python I have two sets of decision variables, for example

```
#Variables x 
x = LpVariable.dicts("Decision_x",(range(3),range(3)),0,1,LpInteger)
#Variables y 
y = LpVariable.dicts("Decision_y",(range(3),range(3)),0,1,LpInteger)
```

After solving the model I am only interested in those variables where x[i][j] takes value 1. I know that with

```
for v in prob.variables():
    if v.varValue == 1:
        print(v)
```

I can print all variables with their value equal to one. Hence, all x and all y variables with their value equal to 1 are printed. How can I manage to access only the x variables so that the y variables do not get printed? I tried `prob.variables(x)`, or `prob.variables()[x]` but nothing has worked so far.

Then in a next step I would like to extract the indices of the x variables for which x is equal to 1. For example, if `x[1][3] == 1` then I want to find those indices 1 and 3. Is their any clever way in PuLP to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x` is a dict. Given two indices `i,j` at `x[i][j]` you have a `pulp.LpVariable`.
You know in advance the indices of you x variable, so one way is for example the following

```
for i,j in itertools.product(range(3),range(3)):
    if x[i][j].varValue > 0:
        print((i,j), x[i][j].name, x[i][j].varValue)
```

or if you prefer to keep the indices:

```
x_vars_indices = [(i,j) for i,j in itertools.product(range(3),range(3)) if x[i][j].varValue > 0]
```

Another way is to iterate the nested dictionary `x` and get the variables, which are the values in the last layers of the dict.

```
x = {0: {0: Decision_x_0_0, 1: Decision_x_0_1, 2: Decision_x_0_2},...
                ^                  ^                   ^
                |                  |                   |
                              LpVariable
```